# Pandas: rounding halfway values in dataframe using np.round and applymap

Tags: numpy, pandas, decimal, rounding

I want to understand why I get different values when using 1) np.round and 2) applymap on the same DF

my df

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame({'total': [25.23, 3.55, 76.55, 36.48, 45.59]}, index=['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'cat5'])

      total
cat1  25.23
cat2   3.55
cat3  76.55
cat4  36.48
cat5  45.59
```

np.round returns

```
np.round(df1, 1)
      total
cat1   25.2
cat2    3.6
cat3   76.6
cat4   36.5
cat5   45.6
```

appymap returns

```
df1.applymap(lambda x: round(x,1))
      total
cat1   25.2
cat2    3.5
cat3   76.5
cat4   36.5
cat5   45.6
```

As you can see, np.round rounds up halfway values while applymap rounds down. What's going on?

Comment: The docs are clear on this behaviour: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round and http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.around.html#numpy.around

Comment: I have the same values for both methods, python `3.4.3` , numpy `1.10.1`

Comment: Rounding floats in this way is virtually useless, despite the far-too-easy availability of functions to do so. What is your ultimate purpose in the rounding here?

Comment: @AntonProtopopov `round` behaviour is different between python 3: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round and 2: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round

Comment: @EdChum yes, thanks. But OP didn't mention any python versions..

Comment: So are you using python 2?

Comment: Note that you don't actually *have* any halfway cases here: the number that's being displayed as `3.55` is (probably) stored as `3.54999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875`, so should round down (which is what Python's round is doing). So Python's behaviour on halfway cases is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented behaviour in python 2: [`round`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) and [`np.around`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.around.html#numpy.around) in python 3 you get the same results:

```
In [63]:
np.round(df1['total'], 1)

Out[63]:
cat1    25.2
cat2     3.6
cat3    76.6
cat4    36.5
cat5    45.6
Name: total, dtype: float64

In [69]:
df1.applymap(lambda x: round(x,1))

Out[69]:
      total
cat1   25.2
cat2    3.6
cat3   76.6
cat4   36.5
cat5   45.6
```

Comment: A nitpick: Python 3's `round` and `np.around` don't always give the same results for halfway cases: in *theory*, `np.around` does round-ties-to-even, but in practice it has a non-correctly-rounded implementation than sometimes gets halfway cases wrong. Python's `round` is correctly rounded, so should always give correct results (and if not, it's a reportable bug). Compare `np.around(0.025, 2)` with `round(0.025, 2)`, for one example. (Both should round up, since with binary floating point WYSINWYG, and `0.025` is actually `0.025000000000000001387778780781445675529539585113525390625`.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson that's interesting and valid, I get the feeling this is due to python 2 differences here but the OP has not responded